# Modify Maximum upload file size text in Wordpress Media

Tags: uploads, media

I'm working with my own plugin development for my website.

I need to modify the text of the Maximum Upload file size (post-upload-UI). I tried with the below hooks.

wp_handle_upload_prefilter,
post-html-upload-ui, gettext

Is there a way to modify this text?

[image]

Comment: What are you modifying it to?

Comment: I need to modify something like "Maximum upload server file size: 2 MB / Image upload size : $set_size(dynamic)."